# Slow transfer speed of 4mbps on a Seagate Central 3TB NAS

Tags: performance, nas

I have a Seagate Central 3TB NAS which is returning very slow file transfer speeds of just 4mbps.

My router is a Buffalo Airstation WHR-G300N and is showing 300mbps connection speed. It is in N (2.4GHz) mode only with 40MHz channel width.

My laptop’s wireless card is limiting my connection speed to 65mbps but I would expect to be able to achieve a transfer speed higher than 4Mbps.

Is there anything else I can check/change? The review sites I've seen claim to have achieved more than 20mbps write speed and I'd be happy with that!

Comment: I'd strongly suggest that you try connecting via an Ethernet cable. Wireless networks have quite a few unknowns - you may "see" 300Mbps as a setting, but you never know what the interference looks like - overlapping neighbor's access points, "noisy" RFI sources. Have you looked at the WiFi spectrum using MetaGeek's INSSider (the free version)? It will help you check some of the details of the WiFi network and its performance.

Comment: hmmm INSSider shows that my router is offering b,g,n, data rates even though in my DD-WRT settings screen its set to N only

Comment: Does INSSider show any overlapping networks from other neighboring access points? What about signal-to-noise ratio (S/N or SNR) - should be in dB.

Comment: There was so I changed to channel 11 which was clean but no change in transfer speed. Will check snr when home later, thanks

Comment: Sorry for the stupid question, but how do you measure the transfer speed?

Comment: I copy a file and windows copy box tells me the speed

Comment: I Can't find SNR or SN anywhere.but it says my signal is -49dbm.

Comment: Well Now i'm confused. Win 10 Task manager says i'm recieving data at 30+Mbps but the copy window still only says 4. i wasn't downloading anything else at this time so what is the other 26Mbps?

Comment: http://i470.photobucket.com/albums/rr70/micahwilkinson/WIfi%20performance_zpsreg4w46s.jpg

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately, that speed is quite close to what I get in a similar wireless setup. The theoretical max would be (65/8) megabytes/second, and network overhead takes care of the remaining difference.

Comment: What does 65/8 mean?

Comment: Merely bits to bytes conversion

Comment: Ah okay. I got it :) I see from the original question, he referred to 65Mbit.

Comment: Yeah, I learnt the hard way about these manufacturer quoted speeds vs what you actually get :(